# delphi Thread ITask.ExecuteWork not wait until Task finish in mobile devices?

Tags: android, multithreading, delphi, firemonkey

i have this code here:

```
fTask: ITask;

fTask := TTask.Create( procedure begin
  while not True do Application.ProcessMessages;
  TThread.Synchronize(TThread.Current, procedure begin
    // update ui
  end);
end);
fTask.ExecuteWork;  // this will stop here.. until [fTask] finish work !!
```

in android didn't wait untill Task Complete !!
------
I'm afraid that :

Delphi does not support background threads in Android and iOS devices !!
----
And if yes...  I think it's OS problem or Firemonkey single Main Activity doesn't accept more activities !!!
----------
This is my git repository uses that method executeWork:

[Wait Solution Link](https://github.com/bravesoftdz/Wait/tree/master)

Maybe help to understand my request..

Nb: my repo not complete yet...

Comment: Why don't you use ``fTask.Start``?

Comment: Because didn't wait for task to complete..

Comment: There is also a ``Wait`` method available.

Comment: Unfortunately No.., that wait method uses the stupid sleep function that freezes the Main thread App...

Comment: Use `TThread.CreateAnonymousthread` instead.

Comment: I use that solution before..  but blocking main thread App smoothly using while loop and application.peocessmessage; didn't work correctly... Can't update ui from thread created in android..

Comment: `ITask.ExecuteWork()` runs the task in the calling thread, which kind of defeats the purpose of creating a Task to run in another thread in the first place.  Use `TTask.Start()` or `TTask.Run()` to run a Task asynchronously.

Comment: so there is no synchronise threads in mobile devices !!!

Comment: i need to force app to wait until that anonymouse thread or Task complete , i don't need app to go to the next line of code while my task not complete yet !! otherwhise it is not a wait solution at all

Comment: @Bravesaw then you seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of what a Task/thread is and how to use it (and yes, Delphi supports background threads on mobile OSes). You are supposed to run it asynchronously, outside of your main code, and then wait for it to finish only if needed (like during shutdown or cancelation). The fact that the Wait may use a sleep is an implementation detail, the wait is meant to block the calling thread until the background Task/thread is finished.

Comment: Looks like your question on DelphiPraxis received more explanations, so for the record, here it is: https://en.delphipraxis.net/topic/9316-delphi-thread-itaskexecutework-not-wait-until-task-finish-in-mobile-devices/